# How to View job performance in spark ui while jobs are running in Jupyter notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I was following the steps mentioned at below link to work locally on my system . [enter link description here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/introducing-aws-glue-interactive-sessions-for-jupyter/)

This is working absolutely fine . Now I have additional requirement of viewing the jobs **while it is running **in spark UI . I know we can see job history but I want to see jobs performance while it is running . Assuming http://localhost:4040/ will provide that , I tried but getting local host not found .

Do I need to install anything extra so that spark ui can provide results on run time ?